# How have other GMs handled 'Cursed items' in Index Card RPG?

Tags: curses, index-card-rpg

I'm curious how other GM's handled 'Cursed Items' in Index Card RPG?

I know that the rules are loose but I'm wondering what others do with items tagged as Cursed or from the Cursed Loot Table?

Thanks.

Comment: Pure survey questions (like this is currently phrased) don't work well here. Is there a particular issue that you've come up against (in the rules or in play) that you need help with? If so, laying that out and asking for how to best solve it should be workable.